# Pointer dereference causes error when using arrow operator

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to use pointers (because I need them), but for some reason, I don't understand them. (The explanation is under the code snipped)

```cpp
void Spiel::SetFigureToField(Figur *figur)
{
    *figur->teampos = *figur->*spieler->GiveTeamPos();
    figur->teampos = figur->spieler->GiveTeamPos();
    figur->pos = figur->teampos;
    this->spielfeld[figur->Startpoint].Figuren.push_back(figur);
    
    std::vector<Figur*>* figs = &figur->spieler->SpawnField;
    for (int i = 0; i < figs.size(); i++) //find figure in spawnfield and erase it
    {
        if (*figs[i] == figur)
        {
            *figs.erase(*figs.begin() + i);
        }
    }

}

struct Figur
{
    Spieler* spieler{};
    int Startpoint{}; //startpoint on spielfeld
    int teampos{0}; //pos in Array | 0 best - 4 worst | 5 spawnfield
    int pos{};
    int id{};

    void reset(int team, int pos)
    {
        if (team == 0) this->Startpoint = 0;
        else this->Startpoint = 21;
        teampos = pos;
    }
};

class Spieler
{
public:
    Spieler(std::string wuerfelS, int team);
    //Stats
    int Wins{ 0 };
    int AnzahlWuerfen{ 0 };
    
    //for game
    int FigursActive{ 0 }; //keepstrack of the figurs on field
    Wuerfel wuerfel{};
    std::vector<Figur>figuren{};
    std::vector<Figur*>SpawnField{};
    Figur* ZielFeldArray[4];

    int GiveTeamPos();
};
```

Okay, the first function is my problem point.

Explanation of how it should function: So a `Figur` (pointer) gets passed in the function and it should place to a `gamefield`.

What I understand: I want to edit the `teampos` in the `figur`. So what i learn is that I should dereference it (so I get the values from the memory address), but if i do `*figur->teampos` it just gives me an error.

The other one:

```cpp
std::vector<Figur*>* figs = &figur->spieler->SpawnField;
```

With this I should get the pointer of the `SpawnField` vector. What I thought is that i have to dereference it to use the values and methods of vectors. `*figs.size()` This is what I tried and it gives an error.

It's clear that I don't understand pointers, but every tutorial says: if you have a pointer you have to dereference it to access the values (okay makes sense), but it doesn't function

Comment: Whatever the "some reason" is, it's very common. Pretty much everybody has trouble with pointers, at least starting out.

Comment: `std::vector<Figur*>* figs = &figur->spieler->SpawnField;` Do you really need `figs` to be a pointer? Are you trying to avoid typing `figur->spieler->SpawnField`?

Comment: `->` *is* dereferencing; `p->x` is the same as `(*p).x`. But `*p->x` is the same as `*(p->x)`, which dereferences `p->x`, not `p`.

Comment: *I'm trying to do pointers (because i need them),* -- But you took it to the extreme and tried to make things that do not have to be pointers into pointers.

Comment: And `->*` is a "dereference a pointer-to-member" operator, and a pointer-to-member is not the same as a pointer to a member variable. (Fun, isn't it, this C++ thing?)

Comment: To drescherjm. Yes i tried to avoid it and i could also type or copy and past it all the time, but i alsow wanted to try and see if i understand pointers. Seems like i dont

Comment: @LazyYuki -- You also need to understand *when* to use pointers.  Taking code that needs no pointers and then try to make everything into pointers just obfuscates the code.

Comment: You need to back up a step.   You say you "don't understand pointers", and then saying "I'm trying to do pointers (because i need them)".   Understanding pointers is a prerequisite to being able to determine if you need to use them.   Furthermore, you are trying to explain something you're trying to do with something you don't understand to us ....   which gives a high chance that your problem description will be gibberish to anyone other than you.   Instead, focus on understanding pointers (any basic text on C++ will help with that).

Comment: @LazyYuki I rolled back the question. You should not post the answer in the question. This is not how it works here.

Comment: Either wait for an answer (and possibly) accept it, or write a comprehensive answer that will help other beginners to understand your problem.

Comment: @LazyYuki -- I can see experimenting with pointers in a toy program: `int main() { int x = 1; int y = 2;  int *px = &x; int *py=&y, std::cout << *px + *py;}` or something similar.  But what you are doing is taking whole classes, member functions, vectors, whatever else, and over-pointerizing the entire code base.  That is not a good way to learn how to handle pointers.

Comment: IMHO, you have bad quality coding style.  Please change names of types, variables and members so they differ more than the case of the first letter:  `Figur` vs. `figur`.  Many times this style leads to typos and other defects.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying use pointers (because i need them), but for some reason i dont understand them.

How can you be so sure you need them if you don't understand them? I really mean this question, as many programmers, even good one, will be convinced that a solution is the best, but in reality a misunderstanding of the problem is at the core of the issue instead.

> What i understand: I want to edit the `teampos` in the `figur`. So what i learn is that i should dereference it (so I get the values from the memory address), but if i do `*figur->teampos` it just gives me an error.

C++ has two dereferencing operators. The unary star `*ptr` and the arrow `ptr->`. If you use the arrow `figur->teampos` then you already deferencence `figur` here. `ptr->member` is semantically equivalent to `(*ptr).member`.

> The other one: `std::vector<Figur*>* figs = &figur->spieler->SpawnField;` with this i should get the pointer of the `SpawnField` vector. What I thought is that i have to dereference it to use the values and methods of vectors. `*figs.size()` This is what i tried and it gives an error.

To access the vector's member, you should use the arrow: `figs->size()` as the star operator cannot access members directly.

Same thing when indexing. doing `vec_ptr[1]` will do the `[]` operator on the pointer, but should be on the vector itself. You will need `(*vec_ptr)[1]`.